# How to redefine default theme_image() function?

Tags: theming, media

By default drupal use theme_image() for render images. How to set for render custum function, ex. theme_cus_image()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your purpose is overriding `theme_image()`, and make Drupal (or third-party modules) use your theme function when calling `theme('image')`, then you need to implement [hook_theme_registry_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7).

```
function mymodule_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  if (isset($theme_registry['image'])) {
    $theme_registry['image']['function'] = 'theme_cus_image';
  }
}
```

Implementing that code, when a module uses code similar to the following one, it will call your function, and not `theme_image()`.

```
$form['enable'] = array(
  '#markup' => theme('image', array('path' => 'misc/watchdog-error.png', 'alt' => $status_short, 'title' => $status_short)),
);
```

If you need to override `theme_image()`, and use your code when the image class is a specific one, and `theme_image()` in the other cases, then you should use code similar to the following one.

```
function mymodule_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  if (isset($theme_registry['image'])) {
    $theme_registry['image']['function'] = 'theme_cus_image';
  }
}

function theme_cus_image($variables) {
  if (!empty($variables['attributes']['class']) && $variables['attributes']['class'] == 'the class you are looking for') {
    // Add your code.
  }
  else {
    return theme_image($variables);
  }
}
```

The problem with that code is that it is assuming no other module overridden the same theme function. If another module with a lower weight (or for which its `hook_theme_registry_alter()` is executed first) overrides `theme_image()`, the new theme function would not be called from the code I shown, as it explicitly calls `theme_image()`.
It is also not possible to call the original theme function with `theme('image')` as that would cause an infinite loop: `theme('image')` would call `theme_cus_image()`, which would call `theme('image')`, which would call `theme_cus_image()`, which would call `theme('image')`, which would call […].

Keep in mind that, with Drupal 7, preprocess functions are invoked also for theme functions that don't use template files. If you want to replace `theme_image()` just to alter one of the variables it gets, then you can use code similar to the following one, which unsets the width, and the weight of the image.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
  foreach (array('width', 'height') as $key) {
    unset($variables[$key]);
    unset($variables['attributes'][$key];
  }
}
```

Similarly, if you would want to alter the class assigned to the image, you could use the following code.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
  if (!empty($variables['attributes']['class']) && $variables['attributes']['class'] == 'the class you want to alter') {
    $variables['attributes']['class'] = 'your class';
  }
}
```

If your purpose is defining a new theme function that is used from your module, then you simply need to implement [hook_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7).

```
function mymodule_theme() {
  return array(
    'cus_image' => array(
      'variables' => array('path' => NULL, 'width' => NULL, 'height' => NULL, 'alt' => '', 'title' => NULL, 'attributes' => array()),
    ),
  );
}
```

In this case, `theme_cus_image()` will be used from code that calls `theme('cus_image')`. The code that calls `theme('image')` will still be using [theme_image()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_image/7).

Comment: I need to use my theme_cus_image only for images with some class. It will be able?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include that information. I also expanded the answer in the case you just need to define a new theme function that is used only from your module, and not a theme function that replaces `theme_image()` when used from Drupal, or other modules apart yours.

Comment: You should never call a theme function directly. That will basically cancel are the functionality that comes with the theme layer. Source: [Calling theme functions](http://themery.com/book/export/html/83) and [theme hook](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme/6)

Comment: @Max That is true, but not for a function that is overriding a theme function. Consider what would happen if the `theme_cus_image()` function I am referring in my answer would call `theme('image')`: `theme('image')` would call the "image" theme function, which in this case is `theme_cus_image()`, which would call `theme('image')`, which would call the "image" theme function, which in this case is `theme_cus_image()`, which would call `theme('image')`, which would call....

Comment: We're talking about different things. If you want to override a Drupal's default theme functions, you should do that in the `template.php` file. In this case `theme_image` is the standard implementation but using `theme('image')` will make sure that the overridden version is used. But if you want a totally different theme function and still keep the default one then you should just define a new function using `hook_theme`. But you should still use `theme('cus_image')`.

Comment: `hook_theme()` is not used for overriding another theme function; that is the purpose `hook_theme_registry_alter()`. Since the OP seems to want to overriding the default function when called from other modules (or Drupal), that is what I am suggesting.