# how can I override theme_image() on a custom node template, only

Tags: 7, theming

Can anyone explain how to override `theme_image()` but only on a specific custom node template? (i.e. `node--artist-page.tpl.php`)

As I understand you shouldn't put things like `theme_image()` in a .tpl file, but the [theme devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module it's not offering up any candidate function name overrides except `mythemename_image()`, which would apply to all images on all pages.

Answer (score 2):

As I understood your problem, you need to redefine theme_image function only for custom template. I found following link for you that can help you to resolve your problem.

[How to redefine default theme_image() function?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54060)

Another way is just override theme_image() function that you don't want to follow:

1. Find the original theme function.
2. Copy and paste it into your template.php file.
3. Change the beginning of the function name from theme_ to yourthemename_.
4. Save template.php, clear the site cache, and reload!

Keep us posted with what you figure out.